# AWK merging two files with more conditions

Tags: awk, merge, split

I need help with merging two files.

1st file:

```
header1
raw1 spec1/W a b c d
raw2 spec2/W a c d d
raw3 spec3/W a d b b
```

2nd file:

```
headerXX
headerY
headerZ
z a d a r z j z u o p 45600 raw1 a d spec1 b d a ....
d a r a f g h z u i d 6054  raw2 a f   a   s a spec2 ...
k o k o j o p s t d v 5000  raw3 d f a f g h  ...
```

Output file:

```
header1 
raw1 spec1/W a b c d 45600
raw2 spec2/W a c d d 6054
raw3 spec3/W a d b b (there won't be number because no spec.)
```

I would like to merge $1st from first file with $13th from second file while splited $2nd (without "/W") in first file with $16th or $19th in second file. If match print 1st file and $12 from second file, if missmatch print only $1 file.

If it is could help you:

for first match :

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++; next}; $13 in a {print $0,??}'
```

and for second match I think something like:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{split($2,a,"/") print $1,a[1],$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' | awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]++; next}; $16 || $19 in a {print $0,??}'
```

Tahnk you so much.

Comment: I am trying to do it                                                                                       awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];next} (($13,$16) || ($13,$19) in a) {print $0}' file1 file2  but it doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do...

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$13,$16]=a[$13,$19]=$12; next} 
              {split($2,s,"/"); print $0, a[$1,s[1]]}' file2 file1

header1
raw1 spec1/W a b c d 45600
raw2 spec2/W a c d d 6054
raw3 spec3/W a d b b
```